# How to better compose Roslyn syntax tree visitors?

Tags: roslyn, visitor-pattern

I am trying to improve my Roslyn-fu. I have a simple walker-visitor `PathTracker` implemented, that tracks fully qualified path to the current member, whose body looks like this:

```
readonly StringBuilder fullPath = new StringBuilder();

public override void VisitNamespaceDeclaration(NamespaceDeclarationSyntax node) {
    int len = this.fullPath.Length;
    this.fullPath.Append('.');
    this.fullPath.Append(node.Name.ToFullString());

    base.VisitNamespaceDeclaration(node);

    this.fullPath.Length = len;
}

public override void VisitClassDeclaration(ClassDeclarationSyntax node) {
    this.fullPath.Append('.');
    this.fullPath.Append(node.Identifier.Text);

    base.VisitClassDeclaration(node);

    this.fullPath.Length -= node.Identifier.Text.Length + 1;
}
```

Now I want to reuse this path tracking in two other visitors: `DefinitionScanner` to collect all classes, which are only defined once, and `PartialRemover` to remove `partial` modifier from all classes, collected by `DefinitionScanner`.

Problem is: I can't figure out how to rewrite my path tracking visitor so I could reuse it in both of them with as little code duplication as possible.

Ideally, I'd expect it to be possible to somehow compose two visitors, so that one would handle entry and exit to a node, and another called in between.

The problem is further complicated by the fact, that generally one would expect `DefinitionScanner` to implement `CSharpSyntaxWalker`, but `PartialRemover` should be `CSharpSyntaxRewriter`, which makes it impossible for them to have common base class. And, anyway, composition would be better, than inheritance.

Comment: What about to append to `PathTracker` a some method `GetPath(...)` which wil invoke inside `node.Visit()` and which will invoked from `DefinitionScanner` like a `new PathTracker().GetPath(...)`?

Comment: @GeorgeAlexandria But who will call PathTracker's Visit* methods?

Comment: The common `Visit(...)` method for node just invokes the all relevant `VisitSomeNode(...)` for child nodes inside. For example, if you call Visit for `MethodDeclarationSyntaxNode` it will invoke `VisitParameterSyntax` for parameters, for blocks will invoke `VisitBlock*` and so on.

Comment: @GeorgeAlexandria I don't understand what are you suggesting. If DefinitionScanner will call new PathTracker() when it needs current path, that path tracker would not have the path, because it was just created.

Comment: And what is the problem to create new `PathTracker` from `DefinitionScanner` and call them to collect path? `... var tracker = new PathTracker(); tracker.Visit(node); var path = tracker.fullPath.ToString();`

Comment: @GeorgeAlexandria I think you fundamentally miss something about the problem. The generic question is how to compose visitor pattern implementations. See the `PartialRemover` example here: https://pastebin.com/4RDwdVPJ

Comment: @GeorgeAlexandria, the only way I see this could be done it is to have a custom `CSharpSyntaxVisitor`-like class, that would define both `Enter_NODE_TYPE` and `Leave_NODE_TYPE_` methods for every node type, and then have an implementation of it, that calls multiple instances of like kind classes in some order. Its weird, that I don't see that already implemented in Roslyn. How did they manage to never need to compose visitors?

Comment: No, as I know I understood you but maybe I didn't write the clear what you need to do in my previous comments, so I [just write](https://pastebin.com/SNu1KSKD) how you can modify `PathTracker`. If it's still not it, let me know about it

Comment: @GeorgeAlexandria, this is a solution to a part of the problem, but it is far from an ideal one: 1 - `PathTracker` now has to traverse the tree to the root and back each time path is needed. Think quadratic complexity. What I thought is to have `PartialRemover` to somehow reuse `PathTracker` to keep the `FullPath` always available during the walk. 2 - this would not work if child nodes do not have parent links, which often occurs when you construct AST rather then parse an existing one.

Comment: if you don't have a parent (you just create a new AST) you actually don't have FQN, just only a name). Traverse to the root and back can be avoid if `PartialRemover` will invoke `PathTracker` just once for `NamespaceDeclarationSyntax` and `PathTracker` 1) will visit all classes in this namespace 2) will keep a collection of full paths for classes (prefix tree) instead of a single path. And in the `PartialRemover.VisitClass*` you will check that class name is the leaf of prefix tree in `PathTracker`

Comment: Another thing, you can convert `PathTracker` to Visitor from `Walker` and it will visit only one node by call from `PartialRemover`. But in this case `PartialRemover` must keep previous path from `PathTracker` to restore it.